# OpenVPN solution/options for traffic reduction?

Tags: openvpn, network-traffic

I am looking into VPN for the purpose of traffic reduction on the client side. CPU load is secondary.

Is lzo good enough to beat the overhead malus?

Are there other options to tune compression in OpenVPN?

Are there possible other options for a "compression gateway"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression only works if the data you are transmitting can be compressed well.  Binary data does not compress well, so if you are going from client to HTTPS sites through an OpenVPN tunnel, you will have both the overhead of encryption and compression without much gain in reducing your bandwidth.  It wasn't clear to me if client CPU load was a secondary *concern* or not... If you are worried about client CPU as well, then you are fighting a losing battle.

Now, if you are passing traffic that can be compressed (raw text/html, etc.) then it might be beneficial.  Configuring OpenVPN can be tricky to get right though.  Google will be your friend there...

Answer (score 1):

Reducing bandwidth can be handled in a variety of ways:

- compression
- caching with a proxy like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
- eliminating traffic.  Installing ad blockers has been shown to [reduce bandwidth consumed by 25-50%](http://the-digital-reader.com/2015/07/09/blocking-adverts-cuts-network-traffic-by-40-makes-sites-load-five-times-faster/).